# Несколько блоков JS кода на одной странице

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Как разместить сколько угодно таких js на одной странице

```js
var random = 1000;

setInterval(function() {
  random = randomizator(60000, 200000);
}, 1000);
setInterval(function() {
  showRandom(random);
}, random);

function randomizator(a, b) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * b) + a;
}

function showRandom(random) {
  $('#test').text(random);
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Заменить id на class не вышло, но я мог и не правильно сделать.

Comment: "как разместить сколько угодно таких js " - что это значит? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: В текущем виде у вас один интервал для одного *div*. Запускайте в *for* например, по количеству *div* в которых должны быть значения. Ведь я так понимаю во всех полях должны быть свои рандомные значения же?

Answer (score 1):

```
var code = "var random=1000;setInterval(function(){random=randomizator(60000,200000)},1000);setInterval(function(){showRandom(random)},random);function randomizator(a,b){return Math.floor(Math.random()*b)+a}function showRandom(random){$('#test').text(random)}";

for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) {
eval(code)
}
```

Comment: Ну вот смотрите, я вставляю в форму <div id="test">(скрипт по setinterval и getrandom)</div> закрываю его и вот так мне нужно проделать ну раз 15 допустим. а он один раз делается и всё.

Comment: да всё верно.  ну или как нибудь заменить id на class что ли... просто этот скрипт я могу использовтаь единожды на странице (а нужно что бы допустим 5ть чисел на странице генирировались с разным интервалом во времени. от 5ти скриптов)

Comment: Moonvvell СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ! всё супер! очень выручили! спасибо!

Comment: @HenrryKavel вы бы не "спасибо" писали - а отметили ответ такой зеленой галочкой...

Answer (score 0):

Т.е. вы хотите добавить к примеру 10 *div* и ко всем подключить этот скрипт чтобы во всех элементах он работал и задавал разные значения?

```
<div id="test" class="qqq"></div>
<div id="test2" class="qqq"></div>
<div id="test3" class="qqq"></div>

var random = 1000;

$('.qqq').each(function () {
    var element = $(this);
    setInterval(function () {
        random = randomizator(60000, 200000);
    }, 1000);
    setInterval(function () {
        showRandom(random, element);
    }, random);
})


function randomizator(a, b) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * b) + a;
}

function showRandom(random, element) {
    element.text(random);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moonvvell/o8h3kbot/)

Comment: а почему если уменьшить интервал ну скажем от 1 до 8 то он одни и те же числа будет писать? т.е. больше как надо все разные все рандомные а в небольшом промежутки они повторяют в точности друг друга.